# Datatables for the multiple columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable to display the information from pulling from the database. For the eight columns the data are displayed perfectly but when I try to add one more column in html and pull one column information from the database the datatables get screwed up. I have attached my codes herewith for the reference :

My html table

```
<table id="datatables" class ="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
     <th>University</th>
       <th>Country</th>
       <th>Total_Pubs</th>
       <th>Per Pubs in 10 % SNIP</th>
       <th>Per Pubs in Top 25% SNIP</th>
       <th>Total Cites</th>
       <th> Per Cites from Top 10% SNIP</th>
       <th>Per Cites from Top 25% SNIP</th>                      
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Data fetching from the database:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


                <tr>
                   <td><?=$row['University_Name']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Country_Name']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Total_Pubs']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Per_Pubs_A1']?></td> 
                    <td><?=$row['Per_Pub_A1_A']?></td>  
                    <td><?=$row['Total_Cite']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Per_Cite_A1']?></td> 
                    <td><?=$row['Per_Cite_A1_A']?></td>         
                </tr>

            }
```

JQUery for the datatables:

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('#datatables').dataTable({
                    "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
                    "aaSorting":[[2, "desc"]],
                    "bJQueryUI":true,

    });
  });
```

Any suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it the UI that screws up or something else ??

Comment: Yest the UI of datatables after adding the extra column.

Comment: try by using firebug...or paste some css screenshot to have an idea about the structure